# Finding chances with binomial

Tags: statistics

I have a huge problem that I can't solve, and it is keeping me up at night. I need to find the lower limit, where there is only 1% chance of getting a result above that limit. I have an example of a binomial distribution with a population of 1000 and a chance of 0.01. I know that the chance of getting 18 or higher is slightly higher than 1% while the chance of getting 19 or above it slightly lower than 1%. Now my question is... Can I find out where the exact 1% is, I know that if you only have one trail you have to pick either 18 or 19, but can you average it out some how? Thanks in advance, and I hope I managed to explain my question so that you can understand it.

Comment: For this distribution, it is impossible to name any number such that the probability of getting greater than that number is exactly $1\%$. If you propose a limit that is less than $18$, there is greater than a $1\%$ chance to get a higher result, and if you propose $18$ or anything greater then there is less than a $1\%$ chance to get a higher result. This sort of thing happens frequently when dealing with percentiles, and people have various ways of dealing with it depending on what they want the answer for. It sounds like you want the $99$th percentile, which I would take to be $18$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value $19$. A binomial-distributed variable can only have natural numbers including $0$ as a value. So, take the smallest number for which the probability is smaller than $0.01$. Then, the probability that $X\ge 19$, is less than $0.01$, when $X$~$B(1000;0.01)$

In hypothesis tests, the $0.01$ is the probability to make the error to reject the hypothesis, although it is correct. Since this probability should be at most $0.01$, the value $18$ would not be sufficient.

As David mentioned, you usually cannot hit the chance exactly.

If the observed number is $19$ or higher, the hypothesis $p\le 0.01$ is rejected at the $0.01$-level.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Notice that we came up with two different numbers. That's because Peter guessed you were looking for a confidence interval, and I guessed you were looking for a percentile (of a certain kind). On second thought Peter's guess now looks better than mine, based on inferences from details of how you worded your question, but it still all depends on exactly what you want to do with this number.